# How to call multiple actions in View in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, mvvm, view

Problem is:

I am using a textbox to get a string **q** and want to pass it to 3 different actions in `search` controller. i.e. `action1(string q), action2(string q)` and so on

Now syntax of my action:

```
 public ActionResult action1(string q)
  {
   var mydata = from p in fab //LINQ logic
                select new action1class
                { data1=p //assignment };
   return View("_partialAction1", mydata);
  }
```

Similarly there are two other actions.

I am using 3 different actions because my LINQ logic gets data from 3 different sources so there different `mydata` needs to be created.

My problem is: I am trying that when I click on *'search' Button* of textbox then all the 3 actions should run and generate partial view one below other in some `<div id="action1">` tags.

I tried to use `ajax.BeginForm` but it can only call one action at a time

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action1", "Search", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "action1",
    LoadingElementId="progress"
}))
```

Also I tried to use `ViewModel` but the problem is that I was unable to pass a bigger model to the view along with these `mydata` kind of data obtained in LINQ's in the action. I have no clear idea of how to use viewmodel in this case.

Is the approach that I am using correct? Or can there be any other way? I want to show result of all actions with button click.

Comment: why are you trying to break it up into 3 actions?

Comment: I would suggest that you take another look at using AJAX.  AJAX will allow IIS to handle the actions (requests) async, resulting in faster response times.  Could you post your AJAX code?

Comment: @DanielA.White using 3 different actions because my LINQ logic gets data from 3 different sources so 3 different "mydata" needs to be created.

Comment: @joshuam : just updated the ajax code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of actions are in MVC framework. The first ones are the *main actions* and they are invoked from the browser one at a time. The second type are called as [Child Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute.aspx) and these actions can't be invoked from the browser but from the views returned by the main actions. Multiple *child actions* can be called under a *main action*. So you have to look into child actions whether they help or not.

Ex.

```
// main action that returns a view
public ViewResult Index()
{
   var model = ...
   return View(model);
}

// couple of child actions each returns a partial view
// which will be called from the index view
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult ChildAction1()
{
  var model = ...
  return PartialView(model);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult ChildAction2()
{
  var model = ...
  return PartialView(model);
}

// index view
Index.cshtml
@model ...

@Html.Action("ChildAction1");
@Html.Action("ChildAction2");

...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839451.aspx

Comment: Good example Mark. Link is broken though.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one action per request. If you want to have 3 different partial views for a singular click, you will need to construct a layout page that includes the 3 partial views how you want them and make sure that your action receives the proper parameters to perform all of the partial view rendering.

Comment: i am ready with rendering thing... but how to call 3 actions with one button click or one ajax request ?

Comment: @Man8Blue: You don't. You call 1 action. That action must in turn correspond to a single view that includes your partial views. The request->action is a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: @Man8Blue: If you want to get into AJAX to complete this, that would certainly be useful, but it will still boil down to a 1:1 concept. 1 AJAX call will be necessary for each partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the ViewModel to the partialViews. Make sure you have different properties in the ViewModel to hold the PartialView Specific data plus the search text. Here is an example:

**Model**

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ProductSearch
{
    public ProductSearch()
    {
        q = string.Empty;
        Product1 = new Product();
        Product2 = new Product();
    }
    public string q { get; set; }
    public Product Product1 { get; set; }
    public Product Product2 { get; set; }
}
```

**_Partial1.cshtml**

```
@model Test1.Models.ProductSearch

<div>Product1</div>  

@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Product1.Name)
```

**_Partial2.cshtml**

```
@model Test1.Models.ProductSearch

<div>Product2</div>  

@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Product2.Name)
```

**ActualView.cshtml**

```
@model Test1.Models.ProductSearch

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ActualView";
}

<h2>ActualView</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @:SearchText
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.q)
    Html.RenderAction("_Partial1", Model);
    Html.RenderAction("_Partial2", Model);
    <input type="submit" runat="server" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

**Temp Data** (you will be getting it from DB/ any other source)

```
private List<Product> ProductsToSearch()
{
     return new List<Product>() { new Product() { Name = "Product One", Class = "A", Type = "High" }, new Product() { Name = "Product Two", Class = "A", Type = "Low" }, new Product() { Name = "Product Three", Class = "B", Type = "High" } };
}
```

**Controller Actions**

```
    public ActionResult _Partial1(ProductSearch search)
    {
        Product Product1 = ProductsToSearch().Where(a => a.Class.Equals(search.q) && a.Type.Equals("High")).SingleOrDefault();
        search.Product1 = Product1;
        return PartialView(search);
    }

    public ActionResult _Partial2(ProductSearch search)
    {
        Product Product2 = ProductsToSearch().Where(a => a.Class.Equals(search.q) && a.Type.Equals("Low")).SingleOrDefault();
        search.Product2 = Product2;
        return PartialView(search);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActualView(ProductSearch search)
    {
        return View(search);
    }

    public ActionResult ActualView()
    {
        ProductSearch search = new ProductSearch();           
        return View(search);
    }
```

Now if you enter 'A' for `SearchText` and hit `Submit Query` you will get two different results (basically common search text is used and based on the search query in each partial view it has generated different results)

[image]